# How locally backup files with rsync

Tags: rsync

Say I have hard drives A and B

B is the external backup files. Every week, i'd like to back up A into B, but only moving newer/updated files, removing the necessity to copy over files that have not been altered.

is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you are in linux, use `cron` to run a `shell script` that first mounts that drive then does a rsync to it. Do a  `crontab -e` then add below

```
* * * * 0 script.sh 2>&1 >> scriptLog.log
```

Runs on the first day of every week, where Sunday = 0, Monday = 1...

P.S. This really wont be a backup as you are only syncing and overwriting the files to B. Backup is termed only when data state X is preserved at time instance T. Where X never changes after T & is always preserved.